# If 'this' in function is a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a delegate that is called when certain DOM elements are clicked using their id or class and I'm using 'this' within the function but how would I find out which class or id 'this' actually is?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).delegate("#lg-menu li, #xs-menu li, .list-item", "click", function(e) { 
    a = $(this).attr("alpha");
    b = $(this).attr("bravo");
    c = $(this).attr("charlie");
    d = parseInt($(this).attr("delta"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the DOM object that triggered the event so you can just use either DOM methods or jQuery methods to inspect it or its parents:

```
$(document).delegate("#lg-menu li, #xs-menu li, .list-item", "click", function(e) { 
    var item = $(this);
    // see which selector the item matches
    if (item.is("#lg-menu li") {
        // must be #lg-menu li

    } else if (item.is("#xs-menu li") {
        // must be #xs-menu li

    } else {
        // must be .list-item

    }
}
```

`.is()` wraps up the entire selector evaluation for you.  You could also interrogate individual properties of the element such as:

```
item.hasClass(".list-item")               // does the item have a .list-item classname
item.parents("#lg-menu").length !== 0     // does the item have a #lg-menu parent
item.parents("#xs-menu").length !== 0     // does the item have a #xs-menu parent
this.tagName === "LI"                     // is the item an <li> tag
```

---

Though, if you really need to know which item it is, then you probably should just use separate event handlers for each item and save the work of trying to figure out which one it is each time.

```
$(document).delegate("#lg-menu li", "click", function(e) { 
    // code here
});

$(document).delegate("#xs-menu li", "click", function(e) { 
    // code here
});

$(document).delegate(".list-item", "click", function(e) { 
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to get the id of this, you can read the id property of the dom element like

```
var id = this.id;
```

to check whether it has a particular class, use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass) like

```
var hasActive = $(this).hasClass('active')
```

Comment: then how would he check for an id..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy most probably it has to be used in a conditional statement like `if`... like `if(this.id == 'myid') {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can log your `this` object and find out what fields it contains:

```
$(document).delegate("#lg-menu li, #xs-menu li, .list-item", "click", function(e) { 
   console.log(this);
   ...
}
```

You can also set up manually `this` for a function using `bind(thisArg)` method
[described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)